# What happens if magnetic field line enters event horizon?

Tags: magnetic-fields, event-horizon

Imagine a supergiant colliding with a black hole and part of the colossal magnetic field line loop goes "through" the event horizon, what will happen to the visible part of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field is generated by the changing electric field. Time slows near the event horizon. The rate of change of the electric field near the event horizon is asymptotically zero along with the strength of the magnetic field. Therefore the magnetic field lines will not enter, but curve around before the event horizon.